# what does the suffixed # mean in the https url in the dependencies section of package.json

Tags: github, tags, repository, git-branch, package.json

I am checking this url,
https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/main/package.json

At line 42 there's a hash value. My understanding is that it is either a branch name or a commit value for material2-docs-content repository on github.

```
 "@angular/components-examples": "https://github.com/angular/material2-docs-content.git#9bd54cb435a675b1880f4026a64eb9f1677e7087",
```

But when I am trying to search for this commit or branch name at following repo,
https://github.com/angular/material2-docs-content
I cannot find anything.

I tried searching the repo, organization and also whole github for this value "9bd54cb435a675b1880f4026a64eb9f1677e7087" but cannot find anything.

Curious to know if this is a bug or I am missing something. What does this value mean "`9bd54cb435a675b1880f4026a64eb9f1677e7087`" and where can I find the specific details for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`9bd54cb435a675b1880f4026a64eb9f1677e7087` -> This is a commit SHA

`https://github.com/angular/material2-docs-content.git#9bd54cb435a675b1880f4026a64eb9f1677e7087` -> This points to the GitHub repo and the commit SHA. As long as this value doesn't change your dependency code doesn't

So code until https://github.com/angular/material2-docs-content/commit/9bd54cb435a675b1880f4026a64eb9f1677e7087 commit would be present in your `node_modules` and the commit usually points to a release version. In your case, it's `14.0.x`